# Gem::LoadError when updating rubyntlm

Tags: ruby, rubygems, chef-infra

I just update rubyntlm and then did `gem cleanup`
now none of the gem command works!
What should I do?

> /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:319:in
>   `to_specs': Could not find 'rubyntlm' (= 0.6.0) - did find:
>   [rubyntlm-0.6.1] (Gem::LoadError) Checked in
>   'GEM_PATH=/root/.chefdk/gem/ruby/2.1.0:/opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0',
>   execute`gem env`for more information
>           from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:328:in`
>   to_spec'
>           from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:65:in
>   `gem'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Erase ~/.chefdk/gem and it should be better. For the future, don't run things as root, ChefDK is intended for use on user workstations

Comment: Thank you. By reinstall the chef, the problem  solved